# Adding new connector to DxH in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.6.
I am trying to add a sample connector to the [DxH](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v8.61/Reference/Mobile/Advanced/Content/DxH/DxH.htm),I created a "Sample Connector" class library which comprises of a class that implements from Ektron.DxH.Common.IConnector,Ektron.DxH.Common.IDiagnostic.
(By referring the [Developer webinar](http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Digital-Experience-Hub---Developer-Webinar) from [ektron site](http://www.ektron.com/))

I also added mappings in CBSvcHost.exe.config.And deployed them in the ContextBusServiceHost folder.
But the DxH is not working after deploying the new connector.
Have anyone faced this issue?
Can anybody guide me how to debug the issue?